# Create a link of recent post in custom wordpress template

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I am working on a wordpress website and want to show link of recently added posts in the my custom post template, I have no idea how to do it. This link will go to a page where posts are filtered accordingly. Anyone here suggest me php code to filter such posts and add a link.

[property search](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GnvIm.png)

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This question it's not suitable for StackOverflow (_and could be closed_) You should go to the [Help Section](http://stackoverflow.com/help) and read  [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), then, if you are sure your question fits the SO rules, read [How to Ask a Question on StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to be able to make a good question and get the best help.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to show latest post.

Please check belwo code.

```
<div id="header-announcements">
<h2>Your Recent Post</h2>
    <?php
    $queryObject = new WP_Query( 'post_type=Your_Custom_Post_Type_Name&posts_per_page=5' );
    // The Loop!
    if ($queryObject->have_posts()) {
    ?>
        <ul>
        <?php
        while ($queryObject->have_posts()) {
            $queryObject->the_post();
            ?>

            <li class="blogpadfing"><a  href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
            <?php
        }
        ?>
        <br>
        <div><a class="mango_btn" href="<?php echo site_url();?>/blog">View More</a></div>
        </ul>

    <?php
    }
    ?>
</div>
```

I hope this will help you.